# How to pass a function defined in useEffect() to a child component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) I learned that I need to move my `fetcProjects` function inside of my `useEffect()` because of the `filter` const. Makes sense. But thus I am not able to use the function in my `AddProject` component. I am getting `'fetchProjects' is not defined`.

I'd redefine the function outside of the `useEffect()` but that doesn't make sense to me, to define it twice.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../sass/Projects.sass'
import ProjectsList from './ProjectsList'
import Search from './Search'
import AddProject from './AddProject'

function Projects() {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProjects = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await axios(`/api/projects?name=${filter}`)
                setProjects(result.data.data)
                setIsLoading(false)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        fetchProjects();
    }, [filter]);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Search getFilter={(f) => setFilter(f)} />
            <AddProject fetchProjects={fetchProjects} />
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <ProjectsList projects={projects} isLoading={isLoading} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: just move out the `fetchProjects` from `useEffect()`.

Comment: no: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: You don't need to move the function inside the useEffect call, filter will still be accessible as it is defined within the functional component. Why would you need to define the function twice? You just need to call it within useEffect, it doesn't need to be defined there.

Comment: Thus I end with `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchProjects'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` and the React Hook FAQ from my link, that is telling me to move it in?!

Comment: If you ever run into the problems described in that FAQ you linked, you can rethink your approach and maybe move that back inside the useEffect
But for now, you're making things more complicated for yourself than they need to be

Comment: A better approach may be to create an onFilter method that sets your filter variable and then makes the api request - that way your useEffect can have zero dependencies and only fire on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least <s>three</s> *doh!* four options:

1. Put the function in state or in a ref. *(Yuck)* (Note that putting it in state you'll have to wrap it in an object, otherwise the state setter will get confused and try to call it.)
2. Avoid needing to define the function in a `useEffect` callback. (This is technically possible by using `setFilter(filter => /*...*/)`, but it's also yucky.)
3. Use `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`.
4. Parameterize the function so it *accepts* `filter` as a parameter, rather than closing over it, as [fesieg shows in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481849/157247).

Of those, #3 and #4 seem like your best options. Here's what #3 looks like:

```
function Projects() {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

    const fetchProjects = useMemo(
        () => {
            const fetchProjects = async () => {
                try {
                    const result = await axios(`/api/projects?name=${filter}`);
                    setProjects(result.data.data);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            };
            fetchProjects();
            return fetchProjects;
        },
        [filter]
    );

    fetchProjects();

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Search getFilter={(f) => setFilter(f)} />
            <AddProject fetchProjects={fetchProjects} />
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <ProjectsList projects={projects} isLoading={isLoading} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

That will recreate `fetchProjects` whenever `filter` changes, and (mostly) not when it doesn't. (`useMemo` can run the creation callback even if the dependencies didn't change, but usually doesn't.)

Here's a more complete example of #4 that [fesieg mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63481849/157247). This moves `fetchProjects` out of the component entirely, by passing it the setters to use:

```
const fetchProjects = async (filter, setProjects, setIsLoading) => {
    try {
        const result = await axios(`/api/projects?name=${filter}`);
        setProjects(result.data.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
        // *** You probably want to setIsLoading(false) here...?
        // And probably show the user that an error occurred.
        console.log(error);
    }
};

function Projects() {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProjects(filter, setProjects, setIsLoading);
    }, [filter]);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Search getFilter={(f) => setFilter(f)} />
            <AddProject fetchProjects={() => fetchProjects(filter, setProjects, setIsLoading)} />
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <ProjectsList projects={projects} isLoading={isLoading} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can define `fetchProjects` outside of the useEffect and pass the filter const into it as an argument for the callback, like so

```
useEffect(() => fetchProjects(filter), [filter])
```

Try it out and let me know if it works

EDIT: So it seems like you're doing this for best-practices sort of reasons, and in that case (assuming you're set on it), you need to find an approach that works according to your rules, such as simply defining a function inside the child component that does a similar thing.

Comment: I tried it and I get `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchProjects'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: @T.Karter - Thinking about it more, this will only work if you move `fetchProjects` out of the component entirely (which you can do, you just need to pass it the setters to use). If you just added `fetchProjects` to the dependency array, it would cause a loop.

Comment: I've come across that warning and I don't think you should adhere to it if the function is inside the component. It's value will not change, so it's safe to omit (at least that's my logic, please correct me if that's a mistake)

Comment: @fesieg - That's true for the state setters you get from `useState` and such. Functions you define within the component yourself are recreated every time. In this case, we know that the function only uses state setters, which are stable, so *we* know it's okay. But the linter kicking up the fuss doesn't. :-)